# System UI Crashes With Firebase Messaging Notification Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

So I've added the firebase messaging library to gradle, and when i am on my Firebase console and send a notification to devices, It completely crashes my System UI of the device, freezing the phone and making it do weird things. The System UI also crashes without notifications, seeming to be only happening after ive added the gradle dependency for cloudmessaging.
 The only indication i have is this error

```
rocess: com.android.systemui, PID: 18646
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 64000012 byte allocation with 4193696 free bytes and 51MB until OOM
    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:651)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:486)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1085)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2867)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2756)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:920)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Icon.loadDrawableInner(Icon.java:313)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Icon.loadDrawable(Icon.java:269)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Icon.loadDrawableAsUser(Icon.java:377)
    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.StatusBarIconView.getIcon(StatusBarIconView.java:199)
    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.StatusBarIconView.getIcon(StatusBarIconView.java:184)
    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.StatusBarIconView.updateDrawable(StatusBarIconView.java:171)
    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.StatusBarIconView.set(StatusBarIconView.java:137)
    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.BaseStatusBar.createIcon(BaseStatusBar.java:1860)
    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.BaseStatusBar.createNotificationViews(BaseStatusBar.java:1826)
    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PhoneStatusBar.addNotification(PhoneStatusBar.java:1429)
    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.BaseStatusBar$6$2.run(BaseStatusBar.java:548)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5765)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Comment: You try to decode a bitmap that is simply too large. How big (in width and height) is the icon you defined for your notification within your app?

Comment: @WarrenFaith i havent specified any notification icon